# В списке множеств объединить пересекающиеся множества

Tags: python, алгоритм, множества

Есть список *equals*, в котором содержится несколько множеств. Мне нужно, чтобы все пересекающиеся множества в этом списке объединились в одно.

**Пример:**

```
equals = [ {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {10, 11, 12}, {10, 13}, {20, 21} ]
result = foo(equals)   # foo - та функция, которую мне нужно реализовать
print(result)          # Вывод: [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {10, 11, 12, 13}, {20, 21}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом грубой силы и рекурсивно объединять наборы:

```
def condense_sets(sets):
    result = []
    for candidate in sets:
        for current in result:
            if candidate & current:   # found overlap
                current |= candidate  # combine (merge sets)

                # new items from candidate may create an overlap
                # between current set and the remaining result sets
                result = condense_sets(result) # merge such sets
                break
        else:  # no common elements found (or result is empty)
            result.append(candidate)
    return result
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/F3SoIN):

```
>>> sets = [ {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {10, 11, 12}, {10, 13}, {20, 21} ]
>>> condense_sets(sets)
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {10, 11, 12, 13}, {20, 21}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def condense_sets(sets):
    result = []
    for candidate in sets:
        for current in result:
            if candidate & current:   # found overlap
                current.update(candidate)  # combine (merge sets)
                
                # new items from candidate may create an overlap
                # between current set and the remaining result sets
                result = condense_sets(result)  # merge such sets
                break
        else:  # no common elements found (or result is empty)
            result.append(candidate)
    return result

# try your own input
import json
from browser import document
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    sets = list(map(set,  json.loads(document["json"].text)))
    print(condense_sets(sets))    
</script><label for="json">JSON ввод: </label><span id="json" contenteditable="true">[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [10, 11, 12], [10, 13], [20, 21]]</span> <button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```

Этот и более эффективные алгоритмы на основе [cистемы непересекающихся множеств (disjoint set, union-find)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2) или [компонент связности графа (connected components)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0) см. в решениях похожой, но несколько другой задачи: [Replace list of list with "condensed" list of list while maintaining order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13714755/4279).

Answer (score 2):

```
def merge_all_intersections(list_of_sets):
    if len(list_of_sets) > 1:
        start_index = len(list_of_sets) - 2
        while start_index != -1:
            for current_index in range(len(list_of_sets) - 1, start_index, -1):
                if list_of_sets[start_index].intersection(list_of_sets[current_index]):
                    list_of_sets[start_index] = list_of_sets[start_index].union(list_of_sets[current_index])
                    list_of_sets.pop(current_index)
            start_index -= 1
    return None

equals = [ {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {10, 11, 12}, {10, 13}, {20, 21} ]
merge_all_intersections(equals)
print(equals)
# [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {10, 11, 12, 13}, {20, 21}]
```

Comment: [вариация на тему, тот же алгоритм и \[практически\] та же реализация](https://ideone.com/zpRZw0)